# should not allow settings menu for non-super user

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin, django-views

main_menu.html

```
<li {% if report_menu %}class="current"{% endif %}><a href="{% url incident.views.index %}"> Reports </a></li>
{% if is_superuser%}<li {% if about_menu %}class="current"{% endif %}><a href="{% url incident.views.about_me %}">Settings</a>{% endif %}
```

I don't want to allow settings menu for other than superuser.So i validated like this in template `{% if  is_superuser %}settings{% endif %}`,but still it is showing the settings menu for other than superuser login.

If other than a superuser login in in my site,the above settings menu in main_menu.html should not comes to display need help to do this.

Need help to resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: BTW, what are you setting the value of `is_superuser` to be ?

Comment: is_superuser=1 for super user, both answers are working

Comment: glad we could help. Please do make sure you mark one of the questions as accepted, whichever your found was useful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `user.is_superuser` and I hope you are using the `RequestContext` while building the context in view.

```
{% if user.is_superuser %}settings{% endif %}
```